# Stack color on bar3d plot using python

Tags: python, bar-chart

I am trying to plot 4 columns data using bar3d command in python.

- column1 - X
- column2 - Y
- column3 - Z
- column4 - e

So far I am able to plot three column data as seen in figure:

[image: bar3d plot]

Now, i would like to stack the column 4 ("e") as a colur in this plot.
Could some one please recommend a way to do this in python.

Code: `plot1 = ax.bar3d(X,Y,Z,dx,dy,dz)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you define a color array by using
`colors = plt.cm.jet(your_4th_dimension)` and apply it to your plot as in `plot1 = ax.bar3d(X,Y,Z,dx,dy,dz, color= colors)`. Since you didn't provide your data, here is a generic example.  In the following example, a color bar is also created:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.gca(fc='white', projection='3d')
x = [i for i in range(10)]
y = [2*i + 3 for i in range(10)]
z = [i**2 for i in range(10)]
#fouth dimension:
fourth_dim = [2* i**2 for i in range(10)]
colors = plt.cm.jet(fourth_dim)
ax.bar3d(x, y, 0, 1, 1, z, color= colors)
#colorbar creation:
colorMap = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=plt.cm.rainbow_r)
colorMap.set_array(fourth_dim)
colBar = plt.colorbar(colorMap).set_label('fourth dimension')
ax.set_xlabel("time")
ax.set_ylabel("distance")
ax.set_zlabel("cost")
plt.show()
```

[image: image of graph]